# Email trigger from Test manager or tfs for result

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager

Is it possible to trigger email from test manager for the result of any/all test case? If not possible can results be sent out in/as an email from TFS?

Comment: Are they automated tests ran as part of the TFS build, or are you referring to manual test cases.

Comment: @malexander tests are automated!

Comment: Cool, yeah its pretty simple then.  I added the solution below.  For automated builds, create your trigger on a build completion and set a condition for Test Result = Failed

Answer (score 0):

In the TFS web portal you can set up email alerts based on a wide variety of triggers including test results or changes to a particular item ID.

To get to the alerts:
1. Open TFS web portal
2. Click on your name in the top right corner
3. Select My Alerts

.

If you are an admin you will have a link to the Advanced Admin where you can set these up at a team level.

[image]

You will want to go to "Custom Alerts" tab on the box that appears to set up your rules, and select other to see all the triggers.

[image]

Comment: i am still not able to get the solution, what i want to do is to send out a mail when my test case is pass or fail once it is executed.
query mentioned in comment is also not working.